# RTL8821CE device is not recognized

Tags: wireless, 20.04, devices

My computer does not recognize the network devices, right now I am using a network cable, but when I go to configuration / networks only the cable appears,it does not recognize any device, the drivers seem to be well installed. Any idea of why is this happening?
I have tried this command and I have the info but I don't know how to use it since it is the first time that I use ubuntu

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:c821]
    Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [17aa:c024]
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [17aa:38c7]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
8: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: You need to post information from wireless-info to get help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connect to the internet and run

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install git dkms
git clone -b rtw88 https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
sudo dkms add ./rtlwifi_new
sudo dkms install rtlwifi-new/0.6
```

This will install drivers.

You also need firmware for this rtl8821ce device. Run to get it:

```
git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git
sudo cp linux-firmware/rtw88/rtw8821c_fw.bin /lib/firmware/rtw88
sudo modprobe rtw_8821ce
```

After this the device should work.

Comment: Done!What now,reboot and..?

Comment: Disable secure boot in bios.

Comment: already done ,what now??

Comment: It should work now.

Comment: still not working

Comment: What is the response to the terminal commands: `sudo modprobe rtw_8821ce` and also: `dmesg | grep rtw`

Comment: ```[    3.405486] rtw_core: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[    3.460971] rtw_core: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[    3.487567] rtw_8821ce 0000:02:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0003)
[    3.487788] rtw_8821ce 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for ```

Comment: ``` rtw88/rtw8821c_fw.bin failed with error -2
[    3.487793] rtw_8821ce 0000:02:00.0: failed to request firmware
[    3.499982] rtw_8821ce 0000:02:00.0: failed to load firmware
[    3.499988] rtw_8821ce 0000:02:00.0: failed to setup chip efuse info
[    3.499991] rtw_8821ce 0000:02:00.0: failed to setup chip information
[    3.505013] rtw_8821ce: probe of 0000:02:00.0 failed with error -22 ```

Comment: You also need firmware.

Comment: Alright,and how do I install it?

Comment: I added howto to my answer

Comment: Oh! Sorry, I did not realize, thank you very much for all the help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: It works!!Thank u very very much!!I've been trying to solve this for at least 4 weeks!!:D:D