# how do I install RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter in Ubuntu 23. "Lunar Lobster"?

Tags: rtl8192ce

The Wireless Network Adapter in subject worked flawless with Ubuntu 22.04.Today I installed Lunar Lobster and I get the message that no Wi-Fi-Adapter is present in my PC. In "Additional drivers" I get the message "No additional drivers available". I scanned internet and found no solution. How could they release Lunar Lobster without a driver for this very widely used Wi-Fi-Adapter?  What can I do to bring back my Wi-Fi-Adapter in operation? Were do I find the relevant driver? How do I install it?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1261902/how-do-i-install-drivers-for-the-rtl8821ce-network-controller-on-ubuntu-20-04 or https://askubuntu.com/questions/990378/wi-fi-not-working-on-lenovo-thinkpad-e570-realtek-rtl8821ce or https://askubuntu.com/questions/1098595/how-can-i-make-my-realtek-rtl8821ce-wireless-hardware-work or https://askubuntu.com/questions/1254355/rtl8821ce-device-is-not-recognized

Comment: What is the response to the terminal commands: `sudo modprobe rtw88_8821ce` and also: `sudo dmesg | grep 8821` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.